# Unresolved Assembly reference not allowed Newtonsoft.Json with MSBuild.ILMerge.Task

Tags: c#, ilmerge

When I try to build my program with MSBuild.ILMerge.Task, I get the unresolved assembly ref for Newtonsoft.Json dll.

MSBuild.ILMerge.Task.targets(87,5): error : Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: Newtonsoft.Json

Any way to resolve this. It works fine without the ILMerge

Comment: I've got this exact same problem - did you solve it?

Comment: I used Ilmerge via the command line, seems to work fine. Issue was when I installed it in VS and tried to build. Didn't find an explanation :)

Comment: Thanks - I gave up in the end - seemed like too much hassle

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this same issue by uninstalling ILMerge and installing [Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura).

```
PM> Install-Package Costura.Fody
```